# How can I convert DataRowView type to integer type?

Tags: integer, type-conversion, int, ctype, datarowview

How can I convert DataRowView type to integer type?

Comment: Your question does not appear to make sense. Can you describe why you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the actual DataRowView to an integer, but you can convert it's value to an Integer as the SelectedItem() value will always be DataRowView, which cannot be converted. Use the SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: String is not an integer. Big difference.